# Interpretation p-values Linear mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-models

I hope that you're well.

A little bit of context: For my assignment, I had to treat GPS data to compare fenced and unfenced deer populations. My question was the following : Do the home range sizes of deer vary between fenced and unfenced populations?

To answer the question, I ran Linear mixed models as follow:

```
KDEbest1 <- lmer(log(hr_50DOY) ~ Fenced  + Season + 
              Fenced : Season + (1|Area/id) + (1|year),
            data = KDE_DOYly)
```

Where Fenced is a factor with two levels (Yes/NO) and season a factor with 5 levels (Calving, summer, rutting, winter and spring seasons).

Here is an overview of what I get with the summary() function.

[image: Summary(KDEbest1)]

Then, I made a figure showing the variations in Home range sizes for fenced and unfenced populations, according to the season.

[image: ggplot Home ranges fenced vs unfenced according to the season]

But here comes the problem: I would have loved to put stars * above the plots for the different seasons to show if fenced and unfenced populations differ for the corresponding season. But I struggle to intercept the outputs of my summary. I just want to make sure that my interpretations are correct.

Thus my questions are:

-> Since (for instance) the interaction between FencedYES and SeasonRut is highly significant (three stars), does that mean that during the rut, the home range size of fenced deer is highly significantly different (three stars) than those of unfenced deer?

-> Since the term "FencedYES" is not significant, does that mean that fenced and unfenced deer are not statistically different for the season corresponding to the intercept (i.e. the calving season)?

Comment: None of these p-values in your summary directly answers your first question.  The interaction is the difference in the fencing effect between the reference group and the Rut group.    You could use `emmeans` package to get the specific comparisons you want, or (I think) estimate the model again without the Fenced main effect.  For your second question, yes that is correct.

Comment: Also as a matter of opinion I don't think significance stars would add much to your graph.  So long as those error bars are explained and calculated correctly.